# JSON is full of "\"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, function

My code is as following, and x is already generated (function getting):

```
var y = JSON.stringify(x)
console.log(y)
return y
```

But when I go and try to print it on the screen (another function, below), I have this in the console:

```
"[{\"_id\":\"blabla\",\"header\":\"this is a test\",\"time\":\"2020/2/2 10:29:04 AM\",\"content\":\"test\",\"uniqueid\":\"bla\"},
```

The other function which is printing it:

```
var tasks = getJSON()
console.log('hello')
console.log(tasks[0].header)
```

What should I do to get rid of all the \ in the JSON?

Comment: `x` was already JSON, you stringified it twice.

Comment: @Barmar ah yes, I see... Thank you

Comment: It can also depend on your browser; if it’s trying to output a valid string literal, it might add the backslashes just because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal actually and not a bug the \ is an escaped char that will be shown in the console.

So what is in the string is actually

```
"[{"_id":"blabla","header":"this is a test","time":"2020/2/2 10:29:04 AM","content":"test","uniqueid":"bla"},
```

when it gets spit out to the console it looks like

```
"[{\"_id\":\"blabla\",\"header\":\"this is a test\",\"time\":\"2020/2/2 10:29:04 AM\",\"content\":\"test\",\"uniqueid\":\"bla\"},
```

See https://www.freeformatter.com/ for more info

Comment: Thank you :), I really appreciate it

Comment: if that solves your problem please up vote / check that it is the answer to your question. Also don't pay attention to the down votes alot of times people don't understand your just starting out.